# Not able to make textbox only accept numbers as input

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

```js
// Restricts input for the given textbox to the given inputFilter.
function setInputFilter(textbox, inputFilter) {
  ["input", "keydown", "keyup", "mousedown", "mouseup", "select", "contextmenu", "drop"].forEach(function(event) {

    textbox.addEventListener(event, function() {
      if (inputFilter(this.value)) {
        this.oldValue = this.value;
        this.oldSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
        this.oldSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
      } else if (this.hasOwnProperty("oldValue")) {
        this.value = this.oldValue;
        this.setSelectionRange(this.oldSelectionStart, this.oldSelectionEnd);
      } else {
        this.value = "";
      }
    });
  });
}


// Install input filters.

setInputFilter(document.getElementById("fldtxnpin1"), function(value) {
  return /^\d*$/.test(value);
});
```

```html
<table id="mainbox" class="mainbox" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>

        <div class="toppanel">
          <ul>
            <li></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="middlepanel">
          <!--mainbox middlepanel start-->
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="maintable" class="maintable">

            <tr>
              <td valign="top">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" align="center" id="PageHeadingTable">
                  <tr>
                    <td id="PageHeading" nowrap="true">OTP Verification</td>
                    <td id="PageHeadingDate">

                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
              <td height="100%" valign="top">
                <div class="y_scroll" id="contentarea" style="width:98%;position:absolute">
                  <!--y_scroll start-->
                  <div class="contentarea">
                    <!--contentarea  start-->


                    <span id="box" class="box"> <!--rounded curve/border  start-->
      <div class="toppanel"><ul><li></li></ul></div>
      <div class="middlepanel">         
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" class="formtable">
       
      <caption>Confirm your identity</caption>
     <tr>      <td>A One Time Password(OTP) has been sent to your mobile phone with number ending in <strong id="output"></strong> </td>
    </tr>
     <tr><td colspan="2"> If this is not your mobile number, you are advised to end your internet banking and call us on (+248)429-4053.</td>
       </tr>
      
      <tr></tr>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr></tr>
       
       
       <tr>
       
          <td class="labeltext col3">Please type in the OTP with prefix:</td>
        
         <td class="col4">
         <input  onpaste="return false;" type="textbox"  name="fldtxnpin" id="fldtxnpin1" class="objinputtext" value="" maxlength="20"  size='20' tabindex="3"/>
          
    
      
          
         </td>
       </tr>
<div class="buttonarea">
       <tr>
        <td class="labeltext col3">
           
         <input alt="Submit" name="fldsubmit" onClick="return sub();" value="Confirm" class="Buttons" type="button"/>
         <input alt="Submit" name="fldsubmit" onClick="return Cancel();" value="Cancel" class="Buttons" type="button"/>
         <input alt="Submit" name="fldsubmit" onClick="return resendotp();" value="ReSendOTP" class="Buttons" type="button"/>

        </td>
       </tr> 
       <tr><td>If you don't receive an OTP with the above specified prefix within 5 minutes, request for a new OTP.</td></tr>
       </div>
     
      </table>
       
       <!--End: Change for Security Question Authentication.-->
      </div>
      <div class="bottompanel"><ul><li></li></ul></div>
 
     </span>

                  </div>
                  <!--contentarea  end-->
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!--mainbox middlepanel end-->
        <div class="bottompanel">
          <ul>
            <li></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to make an OTP page where user will get OTP on his registered phone number. Everything seems to be working fine. I have this code and i want to make the OTP textbox just to accept numbers as input and does not accept any characters or symbols. But it doesn't seems to work as it is showing `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`. I am not sure why i am getting this error.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you do not have input element with id uintTextBox? you have input with id fldtxnpin1 only.

Comment: oh sorry my bad. I have edited the question now.

Comment: can't we use input type `number` here?

Comment: @Saurav Now see you do not have error!

Comment: @Saurav For number HTML 5 has a native solution with <input type="number">

Comment: But it does accept decimal value, which I guess won't required here.

Comment: Yes it seems to be working here but when i am using on system , i am getting ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null```

Comment: @Tranquillity using ```<input type="number">``` is giviing arrows inside the textbox which i dont want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please make sure the that you have your `js` code at the bottom of the page (before the closing body tag) or use the `DOMContentLoaded` event to make sure you `DOM` would have been loaded before you start you code starts looking for a node. and `addEventListener` takes an `eventHandler` which is a function, the EventHandler can take the `event` object as an argument but i think you got it misplaced. something like.`document.addEventListener(function(event){ YOUR_CODE})` instead of `document.addEventListener(event, function(){ YOUR_CODE})`. I will be happy to help you with this blocker if the problem persists. #cheers

Comment: Yes i write my ```<script>``` just before ```</body>``` tag and it worked. Thanks a lot.